# Use a recursive call in List.map

Tags: scala, recursion

I have a problem with list operations in Scala. I'm trying to implement the same logic, that I've implemented sequentially in Java (and it worked) but it returns 0 which I not expected. I've debugged the list operations as I could (replaced provided map call to sequence of lists, which behaves as intended), but I can't trace the last step (map list members to the recursive call of this function). Can you provide some thoughts about my approach?

```
@tailrec
def a(b: Int, cList: List[Int]): Int = {
    if (b == 0) 1
    else if (cList.isEmpty) 0
    else
      List.range(0, b / cList.head).
        map(n => a(b - n * cList.head, cList.tail)). 
        foldLeft(0)((b, a) => b + a)
  }
```

I suppose, that before `foldLeft` the list must contain a result of the recursive call for all elements. Does such a call work? For clarity I enclose my Java program, that behaves as supposed:

```java
private static int a(int b, int[] cList) {
        if (b == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            if (cList.length == 0)
                return 0;

            int head = cList[0];
            int[] tail = Arrays.copyOfRange(cList, 1, cList.length);
            int x = b / head;
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
                sum += a(b - (i * head), tail);
            }
            return sum;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the sense of `a`, what does it calculate? Btw, such questions belong more to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: oh, didn't know that there is codereview site will use it for this kind of questions. it computes number of ways to get change with given coins cList(types of coins) and amount b

Comment: If this is the countChange problem, you are overdoing it. The solution is much much simpler with recursion and pattern matching. There's no need for folding. See here http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change.

Comment: Thanks, if this problem have simpler algorythm then i rethink it by myself before looking to reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check documentation for List.range:

> a $coll with values `start, start + 1, ..., end - 1`

Additional notes:

- In your case tail call optimization isn't available.
- `.foldLeft(0)((b, a) => b + a)` equals to `.sum`
- You mix imperative loop solution with recursion, try to use only recursive list
  processing